# Swift / Refactoring

Tags: ios, swift

I'm creating a view to use it as a subview within the viewDidLoad.

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    let backgroundView = UIView()
    backgroundView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    backgroundView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()

    let viewsDictionary = ["backgroundView":backgroundView]

    let backgroundView_constraint_H = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(
        "H:[backgroundView(10000)]",
        options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0),
        metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary)
    let backgroundView_constraint_V = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(
        "V:[backgroundView(10000)]",
        options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue:0),
        metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary)

    backgroundView.addConstraints(backgroundView_constraint_H)
    backgroundView.addConstraints(backgroundView_constraint_V)

    backgroundView.alpha = 0.9

    self.tableView.backgroundView = backgroundView
}
```

What's the correct workaround to put all the code into an own .swift file and only call `self.tableView.backgroundView = backgroundView` at the viewDidLoad?

Help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend UIView itself and write a class function that would return you this background view correctly configured.  Save this in a file say UIView+extensions.swift

```
   extension UIView {

      class func backgroundView()->UIView {

        let backgroundView = UIView()
        backgroundView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        backgroundView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()

        let viewsDictionary = ["backgroundView":backgroundView]

        let backgroundView_constraint_H = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(
                                                                                         "H:[backgroundView(10000)]",
                                                                                         options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0),
                                                                                         metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary)
        let backgroundView_constraint_V = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(
                                                                                         "V:[backgroundView(10000)]",
                                                                                         options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue:0),
                                                                                         metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary)

        backgroundView.addConstraints(backgroundView_constraint_H)
        backgroundView.addConstraints(backgroundView_constraint_V)

        backgroundView.alpha = 0.9

        return backgroundView

      }

    }
```

You can now access this as:

```
self.tableView.backgroundView = UIView.backgroundView()
```

Comment: Is there a possibility to NOT use extension? Because it was just an example, I have a couple more methods like that I want to refactor to use it in other projects.

Comment: If you have this kind of utility methods, extensions are *the* way to go.  Add those additional methods too to this extension. Why do you think you don't want to use extensions?:-)

Comment: because if I want to use the extension in another project, I have to write this code into the UIView to create the extension, again. (I'm right, am I?) - If I write an own .swift file for my "helper class", I can just copy this file into the new project and instantly use it. Don't I? That is the work around I'm used to in Java.

Comment: Observe that you have created the extension into its own swift file in this case UIView+extension.swift. You can safely take this swift file to any other project. Of course you should not have any other project specific dependency in this extension file. Hope this is clear to you now..

Comment: ah well I see. I thought you want me to open the UIView class and write the extension there. but I now get it. thank you. solved it :)

Answer (score 2):

```
        class func backgroundView()->UIView {
            let backgroundView = UIView()
            backgroundView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            backgroundView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
            backgroundView.frame = self.tableView.frame
            backgroundView.alpha = 0.9
```

self.tableView.backgroundView = backgroundView